# How to create a custom toolbar in Eclipse RCP applications where the toolbar contains large icons

Tags: eclipse, rcp

How to create a custom toolbar in Eclipse RCP applications where the toolbar contains large icons.
We would like to brand our application and allow larger in icons in perspective toolbars to make the user experience more comfortable.

Comment: A related issue in the eclipse DMS can be found at: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=421383 . Hopefully bigger icons will be available during 2014 - Vote for it!

Answer (score 2):

aUse large icons.
the toolbar compute the icons size for the first icon,so you should put a large icon for the first icon.